# Помогите переделать работу trigger("change")

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть input для указания количества покупаемого товара и рядом "стрелки" вверх/вниз для изменения его значения:

```
<div class="product_count">
    <input type="text" value="1">
    <div class="product_count_top"></div>
    <div class="product_count_bottom"></div>
</div>
```

После клика по стрелке срабатывает trigger("change") c задержкой в 1 секунду.

```
$(".product_count_top").click(function() {
    var input = $(this).prevAll('input');
    var inputVal = Number.parseInt(input.val());
    if (inputVal>0) {
        var timeout;
        inputVal++;
        input.val(inputVal);
        timeout = setTimeout(function () {
            input.trigger("change");
        }, 1000);
    } else {
        input.val("1");
    }
});
```

Код работает правильно, но не так как я хочу. Помогите его модифицировать, чтобы при множестве кликах (в течение секунды), триггер срабатывал только 1 раз - через секунду после последнего клика.

Comment: дак сохраняйте таймаут во внешней перменной, или еще куда, и очищайте при каждом клике. Если меньше секунды будет между кликами, то сотрется. Если больше, дак выполнится.

Comment: @teran Дак, Дональд Дак, ну зачем каверкать то так?

Answer (score 0):

Вот что вам нужно:

```
var timeout = null;
$(".product_count_top").click(function() {
    var input = $(this).prevAll('input');
    var inputVal = Number.parseInt(input.val());
    if (inputVal>0) {
        inputVal++;
        input.val(inputVal);
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(function () {
            input.trigger("change");
        }, 1000);
    } else {
        input.val("1");
    }
});
```